# Cable / Device Shielding

Tags: cables, emc, esd, shielding

Is it required to connect Shield cover to the enclosure at several points in a defined way? I am doing EMC simualtion related to this and not sure on what changes I can make.

Comment: Can you clarify a few things: what’s the enclosure made out of, why does it have an additional shield, what do you mean by required - for the protection to work effectively, to meet a particular standard or something else?

Comment: @rishab what program are you using?